# SQL SELECT - order dates with wrong format

Tags: mysql, date, select

I was tasked with ordering some entries in our web application. Current solution made by some other guy 10 years ago, is that there is a select on db and then it iterates and make table.

Problem is, that date is in **dd-mm-yyyy** format and in **varchar** data.

And not really sure, if I am brave enought to make changes to the database.

So is there some way to order it anyway within a select, some way to order it by the end meaby? Or only way without making some gruesome function in code is to change the db?

Comment: Changing the database is by far the most sensible idea. I guarantee there's not a `CHECK` constraint preventing e.g. `29-02-2021` from being entered into it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Date processing varies between makes and versions of SQL. Please [edit] your tags to tell us which one you use?  [tag:oracle]?, [tag:sql-server]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:postgresql]? or what? There are ways to handle this, but they're specific to the dialect of SQL you use.

Comment: I am using mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function for this.  Try

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(varcharDateColumn, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

It converts your character-string dates to the `DATE` datatype where ordering works without trouble.

As of MySQL 5.7 or later, you can add a so-called *generated column* to your table without touching the other data.

```
     ALTER TABLE tbl 
      ADD COLUMN goodDate 
              AS (STR_TO_DATE(varcharDateColumn, '%m-%d-%Y'))
          STORED;
```

You can even put an index on that column if you need to use it for searrching.

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD INDEX goodDate(goodDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, but this will work only for small tables(maybe thousands of records), on large data sets you will face performance problems:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT '01-5-2013' AS Date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '02-6-2013' AS Date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '01-6-2013' AS Date
) AS t1
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Long term solution should be conversion of that column to proper date type.